# Java 2d game finding correct enemy for fighting

Tags: java, arraylist, collision, 2d-games

I am making a simple 2d game in java and i am trying to get fighting to work. I am going to do pokemon-style fighting, so what i am doing is when i press the spacebar, it checks if i am colliding with an enemy, finds that enemy in an arrayList, and then executes the fight method using that enemy. This works most of the time, but sometimes it can't seem to find the enemy in the ArrayList. My code for checking this is:

```
if (space) {
        for (Rectangle collideable : Enemy.ens) {
            if (intersects(playerR, collideable)) {
                System.out.println("Colliding with Enemy!");
                x = locx;
                y = locy;
                playerR.setLocation(x, y);

                for (int i = 0; i < Game.enemies.size(); i++) {

                    if (Enemy.ens.get(i).equals(collideable)) {
                        System.out.println("Can't find enemy to fight");
                        System.out.println(Game.enemies.get(i).getName());
                        fightQuestion(Game.enemies.get(i), i);
                        break;

                    }
                }

                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

`Enemy.ens` is created when i render each enemy. `Game.enemies` is created when I read in all of the enemy stats, and then i add each enemy to that ArrayList. For every enemy i try to fight, it is getting to the point where it prints out that it is colliding, but not always to the fight part. Any ideas as to why this is happening would be fantastic!

EDIT
Code for when Game.Enemies is filled:

```
public static void loadEnemies() {
    im = getImageManager();
    Scanner qwe;
    try {

        qwe = new Scanner(new File("enemyStats.txt"));
        while (qwe.hasNextLine()) {
            String name = qwe.nextLine();
            String origin = qwe.nextLine();
            String weapon = qwe.nextLine();
            String gear = qwe.nextLine();
            String spec = qwe.nextLine();
            int hp = qwe.nextInt();
            int att = qwe.nextInt();
            int def = qwe.nextInt();
            int randX = (int) (Math.random()*(18*SCALE*TILESIZE));  //Give random x coordinate
            int randY = (int) (Math.random()*(18*SCALE*TILESIZE));  //Give random y coordinate
            if(qwe.hasNextLine()){
                qwe.nextLine();
            }
            enemies.add(new Enemy(randX,randY,im,name,origin,weapon,gear,spec,hp,att,def));     //adds enemy into arrayList

            int randI = (int) (Math.random()*enemies.size());

            for(int i = 0; i < 4;i++){      //adds enemy to arrayList to be rendered
                enemiestoRend.add(enemies.get(randI) );
            }



        }


    } 

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: The only reason i could see this would be happening without seeing more code, is that for whatever reason, the enemy you are trying to fight does not exist in Game.Enemies but does in Enemy.ens (Which im guessing is an ArrayList)

Comment: What is returned by Enemy.ens.get(i)?

Comment: @Lex Webb I edited question to include when Game.Enemies is filled

Comment: @PabloLozano The x and y location of the collision rectangle is returned

Comment: So is Enemy.ems a single enemy? if so it would seem you already have the reference to the enemy AND the collidable, so why do you need the second loop to re-search for the enemy?

Comment: @LexWebb no, Enemy.ens is an ArrayList of all the collision boxes for the enemies

Comment: So do you have a reference to the collision box of the enemy in the actual enemy?

Comment: @LexWebb yes, it is in the exact same location as the enemy

Comment: Try something like this? http://pastebin.com/eLaAGY8x

Answer (score 0):

Why do you execute the statement:

```
System.out.println("Can't find enemy to fight");
```

for each iteration in the second loop, regardless of checking a condition first? And why does the second loop check:

```
i < Game.enemies.size();
```

instead of:

```
i < Enemy.ens.size();
```

Comment: oh, sorry about that. I added that line in while writing the question. I mean for it to be after the if statement.

Comment: That whole double loop using the two lists seems to be an odd way of doing it. It would make more sense to store each 'collidable' inside the enemy it relates to, negating the need for the double loop. This is more compliant with general OOP as the collidable area relates directly to the object it represents.

Comment: I tried using `i < Enemy.ens.size();` But i got the error `Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2598, Size: 10
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
 at com.hosfordryan.tileRPG.entities.Player.tick(Player.java:121)
 at com.hosfordryan.tileRPG.Game.tick(Game.java:153)
 at com.hosfordryan.tileRPG.Game.run(Game.java:144)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
`

Comment: Then you have one index to go through 2 arrays of different size, haven't you?